# Given an array A[] of N numbers. Now, you need to find and print the Summation of the bitwise OR of all possible subsets of this array

Tags: arrays, data-structures

For `[1, 2, 3],` all possible subsets are `{1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}`

The sum of OR of these subsets are, `1 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 18`.

My Approach is to generate all possible subset and find their OR and sum it but time complexity is `O(2^n)` , but I need a solution with `O(nlogn)` or less.

Comment: post your code here.

Answer (score 2):

As you having 3 alements so 2^3=8 subsets will be created and you need to or all subset and print the sum of all subsets, By following logic you can get the solution you required

```
public class AndOfSubSetsOfSet {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    findSubsets(new int[]{1, 2,3});
}

private static void findSubsets(int array[]) {
    int numOfSubsets = 1 << array.length;
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSubsets; i++) {
        int pos = array.length - 1;
        int bitmask = i;
        int temp = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (bitmask > 0) {
            if ((bitmask & 1) == 1) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    temp = array[pos];
                } else
                    temp = array[pos] | temp;
                count++;
            }
            //this will shift this number to left so one bit will be remove
            bitmask >>= 1;
            pos--;
        }
        count = 0;
        a += temp;
        temp = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

one best approach you can use 3 loops outer loop would  select number of elements of pair we have to make 2,3,4....upto n. and inner two loops would select elements according to outer loop. in the inner loop you can use bitwise OR so get the answer.
here time complexicity is better than exponential.
if any problem  i would gave you code .
please vote if like.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find the solution by calculating bitwise values. Consider the following points first. We will formulate the algorithm based on these points

1. For N numbers, there can be `2^N-1` such subsets.
2. For N numbers, where the maximum number of bits can be k, what can be the maximum output? Obviously when every subset sum is all 1's (i.e., for every combination there will be 1 in every bit of k positions). So calculate this `MAX`. In your example `k = 2` and `N = 3`. So the `MAX` is when all the subset sum will be `11 (i.e.,3)`. SO `MAX = (2^N-1)*(2^k-1) = 21`.
3. Note that, the value of a bit of subset sum will only be `0` when the bits of every element of that subset is `0`. So For every bit first calculate how many subsets can have 0 value in that bit. Then multiply that number with the corresponding value `(2^bit_position)` and deduct from `MAX`. In your case, for the leftmost position (i.e., position 0), there is only one `0` (in 2). So in `2^1-1 = 1` subset, the subsets sum's 0 position will be 0. So deduct 1*1 from MAX. Similarly for position 1, there can be only 1 subset with 0 at position 1 of subset sum ({2}). so deduct 1*2 from MAX. For every bit, calculate this value and keep deducting. the final MAX will be the result. If you consider 16 bit integer and you don't know about max k, then calculate using k = 16.

Let's consider another example with N = {1,4}. The subsets are {1},{4},{1,4}, and the result is = 1+4+5 = 10

1. here k = 3, N = 2. SO MAX = (2^K-1)*(2^N-1) = 21.
2. For 0 bit, there is only single 0 (in 4). so deduct 1*1 from MAX. So new MAX = 21 -1 = 20.
3. For 1 bit, both 1 and 4 has 0. so deduct (2^2-1)*2 from MAX. So new MAX = 20 -6 = 14.
4. For 2 bit, there is only single 0 (in 1). so deduct 1*4 from MAX. So new MAX = 14 -4 = 10.
5. As we have calculated for every bit position, thus the final result is 10.

**Time Complexity**

1. First and second steps can be calculated in constant time
2. In third step, the main thing is to find the number of 0 bit of each position. So for N number it takes O(k*N) in total. as k will be constant so the overall complexity will be O(N).